# isChecked() won't work

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

I don't know why but the `isChecked()` won't work, It says it can't resolve symbol. Is there anything I'm supposed to import. I'd also like to ask how you would change the text in a `Textview` thanks!

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
CheckBox concern = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.concern);
CheckBox faith = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.faith);
CheckBox respect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.respect);
CheckBox education = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.education);
CheckBox community = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.community);

int con = 0;
int fai = 0;
int res = 0;
int edu = 0;
int com = 0;

if (concern.isChecked()) {
    con++;
}
if (faith.isChecked()) {
    fai++;
}
if(respect.isChecked()){
    res++;
}
if(education.isChecked()){
    edu++;
}
if(community.isChecked()){
    com++;
}
}
```

Comment: oh you are doiing it on wrong place

Comment: override oncreate method and do it in that method

Comment: You can't write logic code in the body of a class.  Where's your method declaration?

Comment: Could you write an answer explaining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create your `onCreate` method first ... and then add your code in it

```
 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.yourActivity);

     CheckBox concern = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.concern);
     CheckBox faith = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.faith);
     CheckBox respect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.respect);
     CheckBox education = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.education);
     CheckBox community = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.community);

     int con = 0;
    int fai = 0;
    int res = 0;
    int edu = 0;
    int com = 0;

    if (concern.isChecked()) {
        con++;
    }
    if (faith.isChecked()) {
        fai++;
    }
    if(respect.isChecked()){
        res++;
    }
    if(education.isChecked()){
        edu++;
    }
    if(community.isChecked()){
        com++;
    }


}
```